# In Python, how can I create a type hint that represents a Pandas DataFrames with at least one column that has datetime.date objects?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, python-typing

I have several functions that operate in timeseries-like Pandas DataFrames. Those DataFrames have a column with datetime.date objects. I'd like to use type hits to tell users explicitly that I expect a column to have datetime.date type.

Currently, I'm using type hints like so:

```
import pandas as pd

def my_function(df: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.Dataframe:
    # [...]
    return new_df
```

But those type hints aren't terribly helpful.

Comment: While I have never used the Library, Pandera is advertised as a library tool to define dataframe structures with some level of rigor.  see [python-pandora](https://pypi.org/project/python-pandora/) for details.

Comment: So it turned out Pandora is quite decent. This is the correct link to pypi, though: https://pypi.org/project/pandera/

Answer (score 0):

you can use an assert statement to check whether columns satisfy respective data types or not

```
import pandas as pd

def my_function(df: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.Dataframe:
    assert df['col1'].dtype==date
    return new_df
```

Comment: this is not related to static type hinting.